# 400 BAD Request while http.post() in flutter

Tags: flutter, post, postman, http-status-code-400

I am created heroku web app which accepts `district`, `season`, `min_temp`, `max_temp` as bodyParms in POST request which returns a JSON with single object `crop`.

**URL**

```
https://agrocare-api.herokuapp.com/predictCrop
```

---

It works completely fine with **POSTMAN**, You can check with body params with `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
district: DAVANGERE
min_temp: 20
max_temp: 21
season: kharif
```

which gives `crop: Dry Chillies` as output

---

If I try these steps in flutter. I am getting `400 BAD Request ERROR`

**Code**

```
Future callApi(String district, String season, String minTemp, String maxTemp) async {

  Uri url = Uri.parse('https://agrocare-api.herokuapp.com/predictCrop');

  final client = HttpClient();
  final request = await client.postUrl(url);
  request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
  request.write('{"district": $district,"season": $season, "min_temp": $minTemp, "max_temp": $maxTemp}');
  final response = await request.close();
  response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
    print(contents);
  });
  return response;
}
```

**Error**

```
I/flutter ( 6462): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
I/flutter ( 6462): <title>400 Bad Request</title>
I/flutter ( 6462): <h1>Bad Request</h1>
I/flutter ( 6462): <p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Note: Even tried http and dio packages which result same error.

Answer (score 1):

I spent almost a day for a similar problem and solved the problem by writing hardcoded http headers.

try this

```
request.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

instead

```
request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

This solution can also be applied to Dio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have your request body in an `jsonEncode` method. Instead of putting ur JSON String directly in `request.write('Your JSON String')`. Use `request.write(jsonEncode(Your JSON as a MAP object))`

Comment: Tried this too same problem :(

Comment: Ok. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59696140/http-post-works-in-postman-but-not-in-flutter

Try this. It did not help me. Even I was getting this error when I used HTTPClient. But after using http package, I am not getting this anymore.