# Why put flutter returning bad request?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a mobile app using Flutter & Dart. I have a put request that updated a database. The request keeps giving a bad request 400. The code is as follow:

```
  Future<void> updateStudent(int id, Student newStudent) async {
    var res = await http.put(
    Uri.parse('https://10.0.2.2:7030/api/Student/{id}?Id=7'),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: json.encode({
      'id': newStudent.id,
      'dep_id': newStudent.depId,
      'name_ar': newStudent.nameAr,
      'name_en': newStudent.nameEn,
      'name_moth': newStudent.nameMoth,
      'birth': newStudent.birth,          
    }));
  }
```

I tried many suggestions. Also I tried to do the request this way [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432761/400-bad-request-while-http-post-in-flutter). But same issue.

The API is working just fine with postman but for some reason it does not with Flutter. I postman I used query params and body with raw json  There is something wrong but I am not able to find it.
Any idea or suggestions?

**Update**

---

I debugged the request and it showing an error on "BodyField" stating the  Bad state: Cannot access body fields of a Request without "content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Even though I am using json.

I also tried to change the content type but it is giving unsupported media type.

in postman I am using put method with this url
https://localhost:7030/api/Student/{id}?Id=7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your url and body to this:

```
var url = Uri.https('https://10.0.2.2:7030', 'api/Student/{id}');
var res = await http.put(
url,
headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "content-type": "application/json"
},
body: {
  'id': newStudent.id,
  'dep_id': newStudent.depId,
  'name_ar': newStudent.nameAr,
  'name_en': newStudent.nameEn,
  'name_moth': newStudent.nameMoth,
  'birth': newStudent.birth,          
});
```

you already add id in body, no need to put it in url too.

Comment: And ultimately, please construct your URLs with Uri.replace(), not with string concatenation.  No Bobby Tables here!

Comment: It did not work. it still giving bad request

Comment: could please include the full url you are use in postman?

Comment: I include the link from postman and a picture of it

Comment: If that does not help you either, I updated again.

Comment: Thank you. But it did not work. I believe the uri is correct  because I used the same format for the get request.

Comment: do you try my last Update? I changed uri and body

Comment: instead of encode body, pass map to itself.

Comment: How to "pass map to itself"

Comment: instead of jsonEncode({}) just pass {}